# How do I cast a SQLCHAR* for use as the argument in a call to .push_back()?

Tags: sql-server, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to pass the address of a vector of strings to a function so I can fill the vector from a SQL server query.  The data will be used in the calling function.  In the following code segment, the MessageBoxA() call displays the correct data in a message box, but when I try to fill the vector with the same data with a call to push_back(), I get an error of a type mismatch.  How can I cast "Lesson_Name" so that it will be loaded properly into the vector?

```
BOOL SQL_FillLessonInfo(HWND hWndCB, HWND hWndTB, std::vector<std::wstring>& LNpointer) 
{
       .
       .

    SQLCHAR* Lesson_Name = new SQLCHAR[SQL_RESULT_LEN];

       .
       .

    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
       .
       .
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, Lesson_Name, SQL_RESULT_LEN,  ptrSqlDataLength);

       .
       .

        MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)Lesson_Name, NULL, MB_OK);
        LNpointer.push_back(Lesson_Name);

       .
       .
```

Comment: `MessageBoxA` expects an ANSI string (which is an indeterminate multi-byte character encoding). The fact that things appear to work here is down to you getting lucky. You'll run out of luck, eventually. `std::wstring`, on the other hand, expects encoding code units to be of `wchar_t` type, which (on Windows) unanimously translates to UTF-16. You'll have to translate between character encodings, *some* character encoding (possibly UTF-8) and UTF-16.

Comment: Okay.  So I went with 'MessageBoxW' and changed it to a SQLWCHAR*.  MessageBoxW likes the SQLWCHAR* without casting.  So does that fix the "luck" issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  That comment by IInspectable gave me a lead.  Here is the modified code that worked.

```
BOOL SQL_FillLessonInfo(HWND hWndCB, HWND hWndTB, std::vector<std::wstring>& LNpointer) 
{
       .
       .

    SQLWCHAR* Lesson_Name = new SQLWCHAR[SQL_RESULT_LEN];

       .
       .

    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
       .
       .
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 2, SQL_C_WCHAR, Lesson_Name, SQL_RESULT_LEN,  ptrSqlDataLength);

       .
       .

        MessageBoxW(NULL, Lesson_Name, NULL, MB_OK);
        LNpointer.push_back(Lesson_Name);

       .
       .
```

'MessageBoxW' was just used as a troubleshooting message so is unnecessary to the finished code.  Changing 'Lesson_Name' to 'SQLWCHAR*' fixed the issue with the type mismatch on the argument sent to the 'push_back()' function.